# What do these Javascript expressions(+!) do?

Tags: javascript, python

i'm trying to translate javascript code into python, the problem i'm having is that I don't know what some expression does so now i'm stuck. here is the piece of code i wish to translate.

```
    var generateID = function(dob, male, citizen) {
        var gender = getRandom(5) + (male ? 5 : 0);//this line if anyone knows what it does
        var citBit = +!citizen;//this is the line that i need to translate to a python equivalent
    };
```

Comment: Converting to Boolean and then to Number. `!` will convert to Boolean and Unary `+` to `0` if `false` and `1` when `true`.

Comment: `(male ? 5 : 0)` is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), basically, a smaller way to write an `if`

Comment: @George he asking about 3 rd line which contains +! not about ternary operator

Comment: @Newbie well I guess the _//this line if anyone knows what it does_ made me think otherwise.

Comment: @Tushar Care to post that as an answer?

Comment: @Tushar I'd imagine `citizen` is already a Boolean rather than converting it to a Boolean it'd just be reversing it but spot on about converting it to a number. Obviously it's hard to tell with what's been posted though

Comment: yes it will give reverse boolean check my answer

Comment: Thank you to everyone that answered, all of your answers helped now I can move forward with my task!

Answer (score 0):

it will convert into boolean

```js
getRandom = function(s) { return s }

var generateID = function(dob, male, citizen) {
        var gender = getRandom(5) + (male ? 5 : 0);//this line if anyone knows what it does
        var citBit = +!citizen;//this is the line that i need to translate to a python equivalent
        console.log(citBit);
    };
    
generateID(null , 'yes', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+! will test return opposite boolean representation for your input. 

if your input is `true` will return false. 
if it is `false` will return `true`
```

for eg:

Your given input is  `> 0`  its boolean represent is `1` so it will do `!` and return `false` equivalent `0` . similarly , if its `0`  will return `1`

Answer (score 0):

it returns `true` if the value is `false` and `false` if the value is `true`